# Get MPxLocator to draw when attribute changes

Tags: c++, attributes, maya, dirty-data

I have a Maya/cpp code with an MPxLocator. This locator has an attribute called "Frame", and whenever the frame changes, I have a function that updates that attribute:

```
MFnDagNode myDagNode(MPxLocatorMObject);
myDagNode.findPlug("Frame").setValue(frame);
```

However the draw functions is not always started, only sometimes. How can I make the MPxLocator "dirty" when frame attribute is changed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the MPxLocator gets refreshed only if it is visible on screen (or at least the point representing its coordinates).